# iPad 2 iOS update not working

Tags: ipad, ios

I have an iPad 2 with an *almost* fully updated iOS 8.  I have an iOS update that is supposed to fix something about ringtones and security.  I have the prompt that is asking me to download it, but when I do so, after hitting around 80- 85%, it says "Software update failed" and asks me to try it again.

I have been "Trying again" for the past hour, running this around 8 times, and I have pretty much given up. Memory is still plenty on the iPad 1, so I don't understand what's the issue here. I have the iPad plugged in to the wall, and I have really fast Wi-Fi in here.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, [Apple do not officially support iOS 8 on the original iPad](https://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/) (or, as you refer to it, *iPad 1*). This screenshot of the "*iOS 8 is compatible with*" section does not list your device:
[image: iOS compatibility]

It is strange that your device is trying to update to an iOS version [beyond the maximum of 5.1.1](http://www.everyi.com/by-capability/maximum-supported-ios-version-for-ipod-iphone-ipad.html):

[image: 5.1.1 max supported iOS]

It is one of three things:

1. A bug in the update software;
2. Your iPad is in fact a later iPad, or;
3. You are *not* running iOS 8

Could you provide a screenshot of your **General** > **About** screen,

[image: General About]

to see both what iOS you are indeed running, and which device you have. Also, a screenshot of the **Software Update** page would be interesting.

[image] You can take a screen shot by holding down both the home and power buttons simultaneously.

You say that your icons are similar to those on iPhone. Have you jailbroken the iPad at all..?

Instead of trying to update over the wifi, which *can* cause memory issues, connect it to a Mac or PC and try updating via iTunes.

Comment: Oh, so connecting to the PC should work fine. I have had issues in the past where connecting it to the PC would lead to a situation where the phone would stop updating, shut down, and show an arrow pointing up to the itunes symbol

Answer (score 1):

iPad 1 cannot install iOS8. The latest possible update possible is iOS 5.1.1.

See this [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPad_(1st_generation)) for more information.

Comment: I have iOS 8 on my iPad 1, I know that because the ios looks exactly like the iOS on my iPhone 6.